# Powershell - Move files with certain date, extension and keep atleast one file

Tags: list, powershell, file

So I need to create Powershell script where the script first checks that the file suffix is correct. In example it could be just ".txt", then it does check that the first two letter in file name is correct (in example AA and BB). After that it checks if the file is older than one month, if so, the file moves from A to B, **but** if there is only one file in the directory with the first two letters (BB) it will stay untouched and if there is let's say 20 files (CC) that are all older than one month it will move all except 1 and it needs to be the newest file.

I truly have no idea how this type of script should be done.. I have only done a very simple scripts.

Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: Give it a try and show us the code you have so far. We can help but won't write the whole script for you.

Comment: You have several questions/steps in your post. 7 at my off the cuff count. You've outlined what you are after, so, just do each step one at a time. Just do a web search for each step. What you are after is a very common thing with lots of examples all over the web and in Youtube videos. SO has rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: How do you want to calculate the difference in months? (e.g. subtract month numbers from dates, convert to days and assume 30 days per month, etc).

Comment: @derloopkat, the days, would mean the OP would have to deal with logic to address, short month, long month, and leap year. Get-Date has a month option. [(Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)], which would alleviate all that logic. Yet, I get the reason for asking for clarity. Yet, the way OP posted, says, to me, they are not PowerShell familiar, enough. Also, the post is a project specification, not a direct my code is not working, question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming source and destination folder exist, you can do:

```
$source = "C:\temp\location1"
$destination = "C:\temp\location2"
$filter = "AA*.txt"

Get-ChildItem -Filter $filter $source `
    | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime `
    | Where-Object { MonthDifference $(Get-Date).DateTime $_.LastWriteTime.DateTime -gt 1 } `
    | Select-Object -Skip 1 `
    | ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_.FullName $destination }

function MonthDifference([System.DateTime] $dateLeft, [System.DateTime] $dateRight)
{
    return  ($dateLeft.Month - $dateRight.Month) + 12 * ($dateLeft.Year - $dateRight.Year)
}
```

Comment: derloopkat --- good deal on the date thing, but your answer is nor dealing with file filtering the OP is asking about, and based on the OP post, They start off looking only for two 2 char prefixes, and then later asking for a 3rd 2 char prefix, then filtering counts by specific prefix(s), before a move can happen.

Comment: Yes, I think OP can just pass the filter so I've edited my answer. If extension and prefix come as different variables, he can do `"$prefix*.$extension"`.

Comment: Also I'm sorting by ascending and skipping newest file with this version.

Comment: Yep, but your filter is only for one spec, and the OP is calling at 3.  So that filter with more than one will cause your code to fail on the filter. Like you, I did write up an answer, a bit different from your (but waited to see what the OP would post to show some effort on their part --- ;-}) but you posted before me, so I did not feel it prudent to post mine, since we're going down the same solution offering.

Comment: @postanote Feel free to post. If you can improve my answer that's all right.

Comment: No worries, Since the OP is obviously really new to PS, especially at this use case, I did not want to add, to prevent any additional potential confusion the OP could encounter. So, added, what I typed up for this discussion. I really try to avoid just giving answers, without a full explanation as possible, so one can get better at their next effort.

Answer (score 0):

Derloopkat gave you a good approach. Yet, since you said...

> 'I truly have no idea how this type of script should be done...'

... this would mean you need to spend the needed time ramp-up of PowerShell (because you may not fully grasp what respondents will provide, thus engendering more questions.) and learning to step-thru needed logic. So, as I said, you are showing at minimum 7 steps to clear before any of the optimizations which 'derloopkat' is showing, then this. I am using a simplified date selection vs the function 'derlookat' provided. You need to decide which works for your use case/goal.

In any case, not knowing how to check yourself before you execute any code is paramount. Never run anyone's code, especially destructive code (New. Create, Update, Modify, Delete, Move...); as you can destroy your environment if you don't have a backup; unless you fully understand what it's is doing, or be willing to accept the consequences of using it. This is why the -WhatIf parameter, for the command that supports it, exists.

```
<#
1 -  the script first checks that the file suffix is correct. 
    In example it could be just ".txt", 
#>

Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Filter '*.txt'
# Results
<#
    Directory: D:\Temp


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         10-Jan-20     17:59              0 awél.txt
-a----         15-Oct-20     14:47           1074 Book- Copy (2).txt
-a----         14-Oct-20     16:45             71 book1 - Copy - Copy.txt
...
...
#>

<#
2 - then it does check that the first two letter in file name is correct (in example AA and BB).
#> 
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Filter '*.txt' | 
ForEach-Object {
    If ($PSItem.Name -Like 'Da*' -or $PSItem.Name -Like 'bo*')
    {$PSItem}
}
# Results
<#
    Directory: D:\Temp


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         15-Oct-20     14:47           1074 Book- Copy (2).txt
-a----         14-Oct-20     16:45             71 book1 - Copy - Copy.txt
-a----         14-Oct-20     16:45             71 book1 - Copy.txt
-a----         14-Oct-20     16:45             71 book1.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 Book2 - Copy.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 Book2.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 Books1.txt
-a----         15-Oct-20     14:47           1074 DataFile - Copy - Copy.txt
-a----         15-Oct-20     14:47           1074 DataFile - Copy.txt
-a----         15-Oct-20     14:47           1074 DataFile.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 DateData - Copy - Copy.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 DateData - Copy.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 DateData.txt
#>

<#
3 - After that it checks if the file is older than one month, 
#>
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Filter '*.txt' | 
ForEach-Object {
    If ($PSItem.Name -Like 'Da*' -or $PSItem.Name -Like 'bo*')
    {
        $PSItem | 
        Where-Object -Property LastWriteTime -LT (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)
        # Or 
        # Where-Object -Property LastWriteTime -LT (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) or whatever formula you'd want to use.
    }
}
# Results
<#
    Directory: D:\Temp


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 Book2 - Copy.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 Book2.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 Books1.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 DateData - Copy - Copy.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 DateData - Copy.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 DateData.txt
#>

<#
if so, 

4 - the file moves from A to B, 
#>
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Filter '*.txt' | 
ForEach-Object {
    If ($PSItem.Name -Like 'Da*' -or $PSItem.Name -Like 'bo*')
    {
        $PSItem | 
        Where-Object -Property LastWriteTime -LT (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1) | 
        Move-Item -Destination D:\Temp1 -WhatIf
    }
}
# Results
<#
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\Book2 - Copy.txt Destination: D:\Temp1\Book2 - Copy.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\Book2.txt Destination: D:\Temp1\Book2.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\Books1.txt Destination: D:\Temp1\Books1.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\DateData - Copy - Copy.txt Destination: D:\Temp1\DateData - Copy - Copy.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\DateData - Copy.txt Destination: D:\Temp1\DateData - Copy.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\DateData.txt Destination: D:\Temp1\DateData.txt".
#>

<#
5 - but if there is only one file in the directory with the first two letters (BB) it will stay untouched 
#>
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Filter '*.txt' | 
Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTIme, Name | 
ForEach-Object {
    If ($PSItem.Name -Like 'Da*' -or $PSItem.Name -Like 'bo*')
    {
        $PSItem | 
        Where-Object -Property LastWriteTime -LT (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1) | 
        Select-Object -Skip 1
    }
}
# Results
<#
    Directory: D:\Temp


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 Book2 - Copy.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 Book2.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 Books1.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 DateData - Copy - Copy.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 DateData - Copy.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 DateData.txt
#>

<#
6 - and if there is let's say 20 files (CC) that are all older than one month 
it will move all except 1 and it needs to be the newest file.
#>



# Assuming source and destination folder exist, you can do:
$source      = 'D:\temp'
$destination = 'D:\temp1'
$filter      = 'Da*', 'bo*', 'Em*'

Get-ChildItem -Filter $filter $source `
    | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime `
    | Where-Object { MonthDifference $(Get-Date).DateTime $PSitem.LastWriteTime.DateTime -gt 1 } `
    | Select-Object -Skip 1 `
    | ForEach-Object { Move-Item $PSitem.FullName $destination -WhatIf}

function MonthDifference([System.DateTime] $dateLeft, [System.DateTime] $dateRight)
{return  ($dateLeft.Month - $dateRight.Month) + 12 * ($dateLeft.Year - $dateRight.Year)}



# then step thru to see how to get to your final use case
Clear-Host
$FileSource       = 'D:\temp'
$FileDestination  = 'D:\temp1'

($MoveFileTargets = 'Da*', 'bo*', 'Em*' | 
ForEach {
    Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Filter "$PSItem.txt" | 
    Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime |
    Where-Object -Property LastWriteTime -LT (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)
})
"Total Files: $($MoveFileTargets.Count)"
# Results
<#
    Directory: D:\Temp


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 DateData - Copy - Copy.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 DateData - Copy.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 DateData.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 Book2 - Copy.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 Book2.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 Books1.txt
-a----         04-May-20     14:54            566 EmailData - Copy - Copy.txt
-a----         04-May-20     14:54            566 EmailData - Copy.txt
-a----         04-May-20     14:54            566 EmailData.txt
Total Files: 9
#>

Clear-Host
$FileSource       = 'D:\temp'
$FileDestination  = 'D:\temp1'

($MoveFileTargets = 'Da*', 'bo*', 'Em*' | 
ForEach {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $FileSource -Filter "$PSItem.txt" | 
    Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime |
    Where-Object -Property LastWriteTime -LT (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1) |
    Select-Object -Skip 1
})
"Move Files: $($MoveFileTargets.Count)"
# Results
<#
    Directory: D:\Temp


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 DateData - Copy.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 DateData.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 Book2.txt
-a----         20-Feb-20     16:01            644 Books1.txt
-a----         04-May-20     14:54            566 EmailData - Copy.txt
-a----         04-May-20     14:54            566 EmailData.txt
Move Files: 6
#>

Clear-Host
$FileSource       = 'D:\temp'
$FileDestination  = 'D:\temp1'

($MoveFileTargets = 'Da*', 'bo*', 'Em*' | 
ForEach {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $FileSource -Filter "$PSItem.txt" | 
    Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime |
    Where-Object -Property LastWriteTime -LT (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1) |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
    Move-Item -Destination $FileDestination -WhatIf
})
# Results
<#
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\temp\DateData - Copy.txt Destination: D:\temp1\DateData - Copy.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\temp\DateData.txt Destination: D:\temp1\DateData.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\temp\Book2.txt Destination: D:\temp1\Book2.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\temp\Books1.txt Destination: D:\temp1\Books1.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\temp\EmailData - Copy.txt Destination: D:\temp1\EmailData - Copy.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\temp\EmailData.txt Destination: D:\temp1\EmailData.txt".
#>
```

So, all the steps are really just this:

1. Get a list of all files by a 2 char prefix sorted ascending by the prefix and
   latest date.
2. Exclude the most recent file by date of the list for each 2 char prefix
3. Move the legacy files to another folder.

Answer (score 0):

First get list of all files starting with let's say AA

```js
$time=(get-date).adddays(-30)
$AA=@(Get-ChildItem AA*.txt | Where-Object {$_LastWriteTime -lt $time})
```

If there was no files within the last 30 days then get the newest file and set variable $AA to the newest file

```js
if ($AA.length -eq 0) {
$AA=Get-ChildItem AA*.txt | sort $_LastWriteTime | select -first 1
}
```

The last step is moving files to the destination folder

```js
foreach ($aa_file in $AA){move-item -path $aa_file -destination C:\test_des}
```